# groovy method that take closure with one or two arguments

Tags: groovy, closures

I would like to write a method that take a Closure as argument and pass to it tow arguments, but who write that closure can specify one or two arguments as he prefer

I tried in this way:

```
def method(Closure c){
     def firstValue = 'a'
     def secondValue = 'b'
     c(firstValue, secondValue);
}

//execute
method { a ->
   println "I just need $a"
}
method { a, b ->
   println "I need both $a and $b"
}
```

If I try to execute this code the result is:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: clos2$_run_closure1.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [a, b]
Possible solutions: any(), any(), dump(), dump(), doCall(java.lang.Object), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at clos2.method(clos2.groovy:4)
    at clos2.run(clos2.groovy:11)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can ask for the [`maximumNumberOfParameters`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#getMaximumNumberOfParameters%28%29) of the Closure before calling it:

```
def method(Closure c){
    def firstValue = 'a'
    def secondValue = 'b'
    if (c.maximumNumberOfParameters == 1)
        c(firstValue)
    else
        c(firstValue, secondValue)
}

//execute
method { a ->
    println "I just need $a"
}
method { a, b ->
    println "I need both $a and $b"
}
```

Output:

```
I just need a
I need both a and b
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest is to give it a default value:

```
method { a, b=nil ->
   println "I just need $a"
}
```

You can also use an array:

```
method { Object[] a ->
  println "I just need $a"
}
```

Comment: No, I can also declare it and be sure that _b_ will have a value, the problem is that I would like to not declare it when I write the closure. What I would like to change is the method not the closures

Comment: @rascio You can't do that without jumping through hoops. You could check the closure's `parameterTypes` length to see how many params it takes, I suppose, and call it correctly. But you're specifically calling a closure passing *n* arguments, unless you do something magic and horrible, the closure would need to accept them.